# Ruby on Rails Michael Hartl Chapter 2: Micropost Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, migrate

I am new to programming and going through Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and stuck on section 2.3.1.

I am required to create a new scaffold for the Micropost resource and to migrate the new data model into the database.

I have successfully created a new scaffold using:

```
$ rails generate scaffold Micropost content:string user_id:integer
```

and in return, I see:

```
$ rails generate scaffold Micropost content:string user_id:integer
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20130711181712_create_microposts.rb
  create    app/models/micropost.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/unit/micropost_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/microposts.yml
  invoke  resource_route
   route    resources :microposts
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb
  invoke    erb
  create      app/views/microposts
  create      app/views/microposts/index.html.erb
  create      app/views/microposts/edit.html.erb
  create      app/views/microposts/show.html.erb
  create      app/views/microposts/new.html.erb
  create      app/views/microposts/_form.html.erb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/functional/microposts_controller_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  create      app/helpers/microposts_helper.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  create        test/unit/helpers/microposts_helper_test.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/microposts.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/microposts.css.scss
  invoke  scss
identical    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss
```

As I move onto the next step for migration, I enter:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

and see that migration was successful:

```
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0020s
==  CreateUsers: migrated (0.0020s) ===========================================

==  CreateMicroposts: migrating ===============================================
-- create_table(:microposts)
   -> 0.0030s
==  CreateMicroposts: migrated (0.0030s) ======================================
```

I run a local host and see that all micropost views are appearing fine and can create, update, and delete microposts.

Now the problem is in the next step where I am required to make changes to the folder "app/models/micropost.rb" to use length validation. However, I do not see the "micropost.rb" file listed in the models folder. I only see my ".gitkeep" and "user.rb" file from the previous exercise.

This makes me believe that migration was not successful, despite being told so and I am not sure what to do. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked in `app/models/micropost.rb`?  The generate script definitely states that it was created over there.  If not, are the other files that this suggests in the folder? (e.g. `apps/controllers/micropost_controller.rb`, `app/views/microposts/new.html.erb`).

If still not, you may want to checkout a git commit before you ran the command `rails generate scaffold Micropost content:string user_id:integer`, or run `rails destroy scaffold Micropost` and re-do that action.

Comment: "app/models/micropost.rb" is not in the folder. Also the other files, previously mentioned, are also non-existant at all. I will checkout an older git commit and retry the action. Thanks.

Comment: I just reverted to an older git commit. Everything works perfectly and I am now able to locate the files in the folder. Thanks!